# Mount without diffing or redrawing everything

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I have a simple interface that just renders a bunch of table to track our data. It takes about 3 seconds to render everything (thousands of table rows, that is just because of brand new data and other things, not the norm). All I want to do now is have a button that mounts a modal. The only problem is that it must be redrawing/diffing all those tables taking about 3 seconds to finish and only about 100ms to then mount the modal thereafter.

I tried changing the redraw strategy before it  mounts, but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid diff calculation for specific parts of your application by using the [subtree directive](http://mithril.js.org/mithril.render.html#subtree-directives) in your views.

One way of ensuring the application doesn't needlessly recalculate the main view when you mount your modal would be to have the modal component's `controller` (which will execute before views are executed and drawn) set a flag, then have the modal component's root element `config` (which will execute after views are executed and drawn) reset the flag.

You can then nest your main application component inside a wrapping component which whose view will conditionally return a subtree directive if the flag is set:

```
var modalMounting = false

var AppWrapper = {
  view : function(){ return (
    m( '.AppWrapper',
      modalMounting
        ? { subtree : 'retain' }
        : m( Application )
    )
  ) }
}

// Later & elsewhere...

m.mount(
  document.querySelector( '.ModalMountpoint' ),

  {
    controller : function(){
      modalMounting = true
    },

    view : function(){ return (
      m( '.ModalWrapper', {
        config : function(){
          modalMounting = false
        }
      },
        m( Modal )
      )
    ) }
  }
)
```

Comment: That's really fascinating. Thanks for the idea!